# Mongo "auth failed" Only for Remote Connections. Local Works fine

Tags: mongodb, authentication, amazon-ec2, remote-access, bitnami

I have a Bitnami MEAN instance running on EC2. After much finagling, I've been able to successfully connect to the DB using the local shell. I created authenticated users with all of the permissions necessary to access the data, and when I run the below code -- I am able to access the DB with no problem.

```
sudo mongo admin -u <USERNAME-p <PASSWORD>
```

That said, when I try to repeat this using a remote connection I am repeatedly given an "auth failed" error from MongoDB.

```
mongo <HOST>:<PORT>/<DATABASE> -u <USERNAME> -p <PASSWORD>
```

...

This is strange because I am using the exact same credentials as I do in running the local shell. The only difference is I'm including the host and port information. I've since also confirmed that my remote connection DOES work if I disable the auth parameter in mongodb.config.

```
mongo <HOST>:<PORT>/<DATABASE>
```

Obviously, in production I want to be able to authenticate. Do any of you have suggestions as to why there is a discrepancy between remote and local authentication?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I was facing the same issue.

The problem for me:

My local mongo shell was v2.6.10. It uses an authentication method called MONGODB-CR [that has been deprecated](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/authentication/).

My server version is v3.0.4. It uses an authentication method called SCRAM-SHA-1.

Try to check your local shell and remote server versions with:

```
mongo --version
mongod --version
```

If they are different, upgrade your local shell to v3. (I had to uninstall and install it again.)

Comment: Thanks! I had forgotten I posted about this. But this was indeed the issue. Glad I'm not the only one who was hung up by this.

Comment: You saved my hours

Answer (score 4):

I had previously be installing MongoDB version 3.2.12 and was able to connect to a remote instance using:

```
mongo -u ‘<USERNAME>’ -p ‘<PASSWORD>’ --host <REPLICA_SET>/<HOST>:<PORT> admin
```

I am creating a new cluster with version 3.4.2 and was not able to connect with the same command.  After trying many different options I was finally able to figure out that I needed to add --authenticationDatabase before the admin database.

```
mongo -u ‘<USERNAME>’ -p ‘<PASSWORD>’ --host <REPLICA_SET>/<HOST>:<PORT> --authenticationDatabase admin
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using more recent versions of MongoDB (server version 4.2.6 / shell version v3.6.9 in my case) you don't have to force them to match like in @Alexandre's example. For instance, if you're getting this error:

```
[thread1] Error: Authentication failed. :
DB.prototype._authOrThrow@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1608:20
```

You can connect with this syntax:

```
mongo --host mongodb://username:password@IP:PORT/ --authenticationDatabase admin
```

Answer (score 2):

Install the same version both on the server and on the client solved the problem for me.
As @Alexandre explained above, it is probably a problem of password encryption.
MongoDB version 3.2.7

I tried successfully with the two methods:

```
mongo --host "your_host" --port "your_port" --username "your_user" --password "your_pass" --authenticationDatabase "your_admin_db"

mongo "your_host:your_port/your_db" --username "your_user" --password "your_pass" --authenticationDatabase "your_admin_db"
```

Besides, make sure that your server is available for remote accesses. See details about net.bindIp at https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/configuration-options/

Answer (score 0):

This is mainly due to security reasons.

When you have access to the local environment, it is easy to supposed that you are an administrator of the system or a developer because you have access to the machine itself.

If you don't have access to the local machine, you can't guarantee this, and since a database security is really important (in most cases), it makes sense not to enable remote access. You can, of course, disable this, but it is not recommended.

Hope I helped.

Comment: How would I enable remote access then?

Comment: It is documented in the wiki (it's just needed to change the bind address to 0.0.0.0): https://wiki.bitnami.com/Components/mongoDB#section_6

Comment: Yeah. Tried that. It doesn't address the auth issue. Changing the bind address allowed me to access the remote mongohost only when I disabled the auth parameter in mongodb.config completely. 

But it didn't address the issue regarding remote access.

Comment: Did you allow connections through the port via the security group in Amazon EC2? If you didn't, the port you are using MongoDB on will most probably be blocked. You can check this page for more information: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/authorizing-access-to-an-instance.html

Comment: Yep. I did this as well. And I know the port is accessible, because when I disable that auth parameter in mongoconfig, I can connect alright. The issue seems to be mongodb centered?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone bumps into the same problem, the authenticationDatabase is only required if you created the user in ANOTHER database. If you create the user in the database you connect to, no problems.

So be careful : use  then create user .

If you happen to create your user in the admin database then yes you need the authenticationDatabase flag.